# SSH Login with key Error

Tags: rhel, openssh

I am at a complete loss here. I have this working on 398/400 servers. The remaining two are RedHat 6.3 machines.

I have setup user accounts, ssh keys and .ssh directories.
 700 on .ssh
 600 on authorized_keys

When logging in from BitVise I capture the following error:

```
LocalSshDisconn, code: ConnectionLost, message: FlowSshTransport: received EOF.
```

When logging in from a terminal I see :

```
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA     
22:ed:e8:ce:f3:e0:e0:68:a7:33:e9:db:ac:7d:5f:e6:a9:93:93:b7
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: Wrote 656 bytes for a total of 1949
Connection closed by 10.200.10.121
```

I have no idea where to go from here? I've been doing this for 15 years and have never seen an issue like this.

Thanks!

Comment: http://www.indoblog.me/2015/03/download-bitvise-ssh-client-versi-624.html Proxy Line Problems Which One For All Protocols HTTP SOCKS 4 SOCKS 5 proxy Using either the User or Operator Default Proxy Squid Proxy so that there are obstacles on the path to the proxy. (gibberish to me, but you decipher it, I am sure, auto translated from some language to English, sorry, best I could find atm)

Comment: Ha I saw that as well and went what? It was kind of gibberish to me as well

Comment: sorry to hear that, will try  harder tomorrow - if not solved already

Comment: What can you see in the server logs?